# Ext.Defer gives getAsynchronousLoad Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, combobox, proxy

I've just defined a combobox. Firstly it loads a `country`list and when select a value it's fire a `change` event which doing a `ajax` query to DB within searching service;

The thing; this configuration works pretty well when I click and open combobox items. But when I'm typing to combobox's field it's fires listener's `store.load` and because of none of country selected yet, the search query url gives not found errors of course.

```
{
                    xtype: 'countrycombo',
                    itemId: 'countryName',
                    name:'country',
                    afterLabelTextTpl: MyApp.Globals.required,
                    allowBlank: false,
                    flex: 1,
                    // forceSelection: false,
                    // typeAhead: true,
                    // typeAheadDelay: 50,
                    store: {
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            // isSynchronous: true,
                            url: MyApp.Globals.getUrl() + '/country/list?limit=250',
                            // timeout: 300000,
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                rootProperty: 'data'
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 0,
                        sorters: 'description',
                        autoLoad: true
                    }
                    ,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (combo, countryId) {
                            var cityStore = Ext.getStore('cityCombo');
                            cityStore.getProxy()
                                .setUrl(MyAppp.Globals.getUrl() + '/city/view/search?query=countryid:'+ countryId);
                            // Ext.defer(cityStore.load, 100);
                            cityStore.load();
                        }
                    }
                },
```

I've tried several things as you see in code above to set a delay/timeout for **load** during typing to combobox text field; `Ext.defer`, `timeout`config on proxy, `typeAhead` config on combo but none of them worked!

I thought that `Ext.defer` is the best solution but it gives this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: me.getAsynchronousLoad is not a function at load (ProxyStore.js?_dc=15169)`

How can I set a delay/timeout to combobox to fires `load` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well.. I've tried to implement @Leroy's advice but somehow `Ext.defer` did not fire `cityStore.load`. So I keep examine similar situations on google and found [Ext.util.DelayedTask](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.util.DelayedTask.html)

So configured the `listerens`'s `change` to this and it's works pretty well;

```
listeners: {
                            change: function (combo, countryId) {
                                var alert = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function () {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Info!', 'Please select a country');
                                });

                                var cityStore = Ext.getStore('cityCombo');

                                cityStore.getProxy().setUrl(MyApp.Globals.getUrl() + '/city/view/search?query=countryid:'+ countryId);

                                if (typeof countryId === 'number') {
                                    cityStore.load();
                                } else {
                                    alert.delay(8000);

                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Ext.defer(cityStore.load, 100);

try using this :

```
Ext.defer(function(){

cityStore.load

}, 300);
```

If this doest work, try increasing your delay

or you can put a logic before loading

like this :

```
if(countryId.length == 5){

cityStore.load

}
```

This will ensure that you Entered the right values before loading

Hope this helps, and Goodluck on your project

Comment: Dear @Leroy as I've explaned on my own answer; I couldn't implement your samples but I've `Ext.util.DelayedTask`. Thanks a lot.